# Equations system: $v_1 = \displaystyle \frac{v}{2}\left(x_{1}S-x_{2}\sqrt{1-S^2}+x_{3}C-x_{4}\sqrt{1-C^2}\right)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, systems-of-equations

I have the following 2 equations with the unknowns: $S$ and $C$.

$v_1 = \displaystyle \frac{v}{2}\left(x_{1}S-x_{2}\sqrt{1-S^2}+x_{3}C-x_{4}\sqrt{1-C^2}\right)$

$v_2 = \displaystyle \frac{v}{2}\left(y_{1}S-y_{2}\sqrt{1-S^2}+y_{3}C-y_{4}\sqrt{1-C^2}\right)$

Initial I had 2 equations written using $\cos$ and $\sin$ functions, but I managed to rewrite them and bringing them to this algebraic form.
Any idea or solution to find out $S$ and $C$ is very welcoming.

Comment: Can you kindly edit your post to include the two original equations with $\bf{cos}$ and $\bf{sin}$ functions? We want to see whether it is easier to separate the two unknown angles than $\pmb{S}$ and $\pmb{C}$.  By the way, we are not promising anything right now.